# Load different services is Startup.cs ConfigureServices based on Endpoint or URL Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url, path, endpoint

I am trying to load different services depending on the endpoints I am using or the URL path whichever is easier.

Example:
if the URL/Endpoint is ...`Foo/Bar/`  -- load the first set of services
if the URL/Endpoint is ...`Foo/`  -- load the second set of services

Here is my code

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOptions();

            var graphBaseUrl = Configuration["Graph:BaseUrl"]; //"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0";

            var userReadScope = "user.read";

            var Bar= "true";

            // List of scopes required
            string[] initialScopes = new string[] { userReadScope };


            if (Bar == "false")
            {
                services.AddMvc()
                    .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
                services.AddSession();
            }
            else
            {
                services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, configSectionName: "ABC")
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                    .AddMicrosoftGraph(graphBaseUrl, userReadScope)
                    .AddSessionTokenCaches();

                services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
                {
                    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();
                    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
            }

            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(async endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Site}/{id?}"
                    );
                    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                }
            );
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "Bar",
                        pattern: "{controller=Bar}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                    );
                    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                }
            );
        }
```

I have a "hard coded" variable

```
var Bar = "true";
```

and the code and logic works. What I need is to dynamically set the "Bar" variable based on either the endpoint or the URL path (If it contains the path /Bar) or even just if the default endpoint is not being used?

I have tried to use the services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); but all my attempts have failed.

Comment: Sounds like [the XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why exactly do you want this?

Comment: Im trying to use 2 different login autherntication processes with the same application based on the endpoint/URL. One that uses the MSAL JS method with a popup login window and one that used built-in authenticated login (no popup window). I have one enviroment that is very restrictive and the popup login option is the only method that works.  I know I should just use one or the other but the one that requires the popup is a very limited audience and I don't want to force all the other users to deal with the popup window If I can help it.

Answer (score 0):

Once the services are build. You cannot change. So you have to register all the needed services, then do something in the processing pipeline.
For authentication, you could use the attribute `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ="xxxxx")]` at top of a controller or action to specify what authentication method it uses.  Every authentication method has a "scheme name". Sometimes they are hidden, you need to dig them out.

For MSAL, the scheme name is `"OpenIdConnect"` or you could use `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`.

For build-in identity, hte scheme name is `"Identity.Application"`.

In your MSAL code, the `AddControllersWithViews` part creat an option that apply this scheme to every action. You need to delete that option.
This is how my sample project program.cs like

```
//MSAL authentication part.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI(); 


//the build-in authentication service part
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();
```

Then I used different scheme for different action. "privacy" apge use MSAL("openidconnect"), "employee" page use build in scheme.
[image]

Test result. You can see "privacy" and "employee" asking for different authentication method.
[image]

similarly，adding the authorize on top of the bar controller will work for whole controller.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer and I will look into this approch. However, for now, all I am really looking for is a way to dynamically set the "Bar" variable based the URL path.

A more simple example of what I need is:
if the URL is Foo/Bar/ -- Set Bar = 2
if the UR is Foo/ -- Set Bar = 1

Comment: @KenNewman The services are registered only when the application start. They will not register again when every request come in. So in my opinion, you could make condition on every request URL. But it is not possible to register anything service after the condition.